# Define a dialect and change default dialect

Tags: xetex, listings

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinelanguage[3]{Python}[]{Python}{morekeywords={yield,goto}}

\lstset{
  defaultdialect=[3]Python % Line A
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
yield
goto
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I defined dialect `[3]Python` based on the Python provided by the package. `[3]Python` has two more keywords.

If I remove Line A, and set `language={[3]Python}` for every `\begin{lstlisting}`, the file compiles fine.

But I would like to make use of the defaultdialect option, and change the default dialect of Python from empty dialect to the [3] dialect. However, when I compile the file, xelatex reports error

> ! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]. \zap@space #1
> #2->#1
> \ifx #2@empty \else \expandafter \zap@space \fi #2 l.14 \begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
>
> No pages of output.

How do I fix it?